# cy.session() issues with cypress 10

Tags: javascript, session, cypress

I am using cy.session(baseurl) in cypress10 for session storage in before(), in their actual documentation, it says once you store the session, you can call page paths by cy.visit(/page1') in each it() block you want. However, in my case, it says 404 not found unless I use cy.visit(baseurl + '/page1'). Can someone help me with this why the correct implementation i.e. ('/page1') is not working in it() block.
code snipped:

```
    before("Open Website and Login", () => {
        cy.session([host, username, password], () => {
            cy.visit(host)
            lgn.fillSignUpEmail(username);
            lgn.fillSignUpPassword(password);
            lgn.clickSubmitButton();
            cy.wait(5000);


        })
    })

    // ******* Dashboard Page ***********

    it("Check Dashboard Page", () => {
        cy.visit(host + '/admin');
        cy.wait(5000);
        cy.title().should('eq', 'Dashboard | Menu Admin');
        dbrd.clickDashboard();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `baseUrl` in configuration which will allow you to specify `cy.visit('/admin')` without adding baseUrl every time.

See [Setting a global baseUrl](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Setting-a-global-baseUrl)

> Best Practice: Set a baseUrl in your Cypress configuration

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
  }
})
```

---

The `cy.session()` command is a cache, as such you need to use it in `beforeEach()` not `before()`.

```js
beforeEach("Open Website and Login", () => {
  cy.session([host, username, password], () => {
    cy.visit('/')                          // config baseUrl pre-pended to '/'
    lgn.fillSignUpEmail(username);
    lgn.fillSignUpPassword(password);
    lgn.clickSubmitButton();
    cy.wait(5000);
  })
})

// ******* Dashboard Page ***********

it("Check Dashboard Page", () => {
  cy.visit('/admin');                     // config baseUrl pre-pended to '/admin'
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using .env file as I don't want to commit URLs and credentials on the git. I configured the base URL in the .env and used it as above. Its working with (URL + '/page path') but not as ('/page path).

Comment: Must be a CIA site? `baseUrl` is not usually a security risk.

Comment: I used it as explained above with beforeEach() but the problem is still there it never goes to page path until I define it with (host + page path) where the host is saved in .env file.